# Unreal Engine 4, import with c++?

Tags: unreal-engine4, fbx

I need to import an fbx into UE4 using c++. This is to eventually write a batch importer that sets up material connects etc upon import.

I am, however, stuck at the first hurdle.

I cannot find any info on this anywhere.

How can I load an fbx model into the editor using c++ ?

edit:

I do not need to do this at runtime, I just need to import the models into the editor, and adjust their location/material settings as I do so..

Answer (score 1):

Parse the .fbx (there are enough docs), then [create the mesh at runtime](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Procedural_Mesh_Generation) would be one way.

If you only need the editor stuff, check out the FbxMainImport.cpp

```
FFbxImporter::OpenFile
FbxNode* GetFirstFbxMesh(FbxNode* Node, bool bIsSkelMesh)
```

etc...

Comment: thanks! It is parsing the fbx I am having issues with. Do I need to create a UFactory for the import? or is there an easy way? Maybe I am looking for the wrong thing, but I can't find any helpful info.

Comment: Manually, would be my first guess, as I strongly assume that UEs .fbx importer is not going to end up in the runtime, but only the editor. The format is well documented and easy to parse, though.

Comment: Sorry i may not have been clear, (question edited) I don't need to do this at runtime. Just into the editor.